# How to read subprocess immediatly using row buffering?

Tags: python, io

I try to get output from `a.exe`, but something went wrong

```
a = subprocess.Popen('a.exe', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True,
                     bufsize=1, encoding='ASCII')
output = a.stdout.readline()
```

```
// a.exe
printf("output\n");
...
scanf("%s",input);
```

I find `a.exe` stops at `scanf` but didn't output anything even though I set `universal_newlines=True` and `bufsize=1` How can I get the output immediatly?
(In Windows)

Comment: You need to change the C program to not buffer its output. Use `setvbuf()` to turn off buffering, or put `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf()`.

Comment: But if you want to control an interactive program, checkout `pexpect` instead of `subprocess`.  It uses a pty to work around the buffering problem.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! Good idea to use pexpect instead. I was stuck in subprocess trap all the way.